# GpsGate REST API Pre-flight

Tags: axios

I'am having this CORS pre-flight issue with following code

```
var ax = axios.create({
   baseURL: "http://<REDACTED>/comGpsGate/api/v.1/applications",
   headers: {
       common: { Authorization: "wzKGSAkC8UU2<REDACTED>" }
   }
});
ax.get('/4/users/15/tracks?Date=2018-9-24');
```

[image: FireFox Console]

I'am having success using cURL, Postman.

```
curl -i -X GET "http://<REDACTED>/comGpsGate/api/v.1/applications/4/users/15/tracks?Date=2018-9-24" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: wzKGSAkC8UU2<REDACTED>"
```

But having issues while accessing from webpage using axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to latest version fixed the issue